# XSL error: An xsl:template element must not contain an xsl:template element

Tags: xml, xslt

After executing xsl, getting an error:

> because of: An xsl:template element must not contain an xsl:template
>   element; SystemID:
>   file:/C:/xslt/CombineToOutput.xsl;
>   Line#: 19; Column#: -1 Element must be used only at top level of
>   stylesheet; SystemID:
>   file:/C:/xslt/CombineToOutput.xsl;
>   Line#: 19; Column#: -1 (Failed to compile stylesheet. 2 errors
>   detected.) (Failed to compile stylesheet. 2 errors detected.)

the XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9">

    <!--  STICKER INFO COMBINETOOUTPUT-->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()/*[name()!='DbResponse']"/>       
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*:PurchaseOrder">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*:PurchaseOrderLine/Item/CustomerItemID/ID"/>

        <xsl:template match="*:PurchaseOrderLine/Item/CustomerItemID/ID">
            <xsl:variable name="ArtNr" select="/*/ProcessPurchaseOrder/DataArea/PurchaseOrder/PurchaseOrderLine/Item/CustomerItemID/ID"/>
            <xsl:variable name="WepNr" select="/*/DbResponse/ResultSet/Row[Cell[@name='ARTNR']=$ArtNr]/Cell[@name='WEPNR']"/>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:if test="$WepNr!=''">
                    <LineNumber><xsl:value-of select="$WepNr"/></LineNumber>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I'm having trouble here understanding why you can't understand this error message, which as the answer states is perfectly clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is clear.

```
<xsl:template match="*:PurchaseOrder">
```

contains

```
    <xsl:template match="*:PurchaseOrderLine/Item/CustomerItemID/ID">
```

and this is not allowed in XSLT. Just move the inner template so it is no longer contained in the outer template.